# Why channelInactive on server is called when the client is killed by SIGKILL?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, netty

There is an echo server and an echo client. When I use `kill -9 <client_pid>` to kill client process, the `channelInactive` on server is called.

The client is killed by `SIGKILL`, so it should have no time to actively close this socket. As a result, the `channelInactive` on server should not be trigged, which did happen.

Why `channelInactive` on server is called when the client is killed by `SIGKILL`?

The EchoServer class

```
public class EchoServer {
  private final int port;

  public EchoServer(int port) {
    this.port = port;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    int port = 9001;
    new EchoServer(port).start();
  }

  public void start() throws InterruptedException {
    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();

    try {
      ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
      bootstrap
          .group(group)
          .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
          .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
            @Override
            protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
              ch.pipeline()
                .addLast(new ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter() {
                  @Override
                  public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("channelInactive()");
                  }
                });
            }
          });

      ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port)).sync();
      future.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } finally {
      group.shutdownGracefully().sync();
    }
  }
}
```

The EchoClient class

```
public class EchoClient {
  private final String host;
  private final int port;

  public EchoClient(String host, int port) {
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
  }

  public void start() throws InterruptedException {
    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try {
      Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
      bootstrap
          .group(group)
          .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
          .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
            @Override
            protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
            }
          });

      ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port)).sync();
      future.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } finally {
      group.shutdownGracefully().sync();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    new EchoClient("localhost", 9001).start();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The client is killed by SIGKILL, so it should have no time to actively close this socket.

The client application does not actively close the socket. The clients OS kernel implicitly closes a socket if no local application is having it open anymore.

Comment: Thanks very much! If the client computer is powered off suddenly, this socket would not be closed. This is, is the situation where the client is killed by SIGKILL different from the situation where the client is powered off?

Comment: @ZiheLiu: Yes, with SIGKILL the application exits but the OS kernel is still running and is able to close the socket. With a sudden power off with no shutdown of the OS  there would be no way for the OS to properly close the socket.